# Why does Android WebView not open page for a specific website?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-webview

I have implemented a webview in my Android Application, it works perfectly fine for webpages such as Facebook.com and similar, but for the specific page I wan't to include, the screen remains blank. I have tried to open the webpage from my Chrome browser on the phone, so I know it works from a phone, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work from the webview, could it be some settings the owners of buildai.space have on their website? I have even purchased app runs, so that shouldn't be an issue. Hope somebody can help me!

This is the code:

```
override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            _binding = FragmentPlanYourTripBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

            Log.w(ContentValues.TAG, "Opened itinerary")

            val webView = binding.webView
            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
            webView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient()) //open urls inside browser


            // load the URL you want to redirect to in the WebView
            //webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com")
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.buildai.space/app/dae3da25-888e-448f-b15c-5a20ca4ca961")

            return binding.root
        }
```

And this is from the console when I try to run it:

```
W/ContentValues: Opened itinerary
W/achelor.voyage: Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/cr_media: registerBluetoothIntentsIfNeeded: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime image/vnd.android.heic
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(291)] "Initialized app ", source: https://www.buildai.space/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-e93cf2deab20c74e.js (291)
I/achelor.voyage: WaitForGcToComplete blocked RunEmptyCheckpoint on ProfileSaver for 8.949ms
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1251)] "User  null", source: https://www.buildai.space/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-e93cf2deab20c74e.js (1251)
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: Have you added BLUETOOTH permission in Manifest.XML file?

Comment: I tried that as well, but nothing new happens. I do think it's the following lines that create problems/tell me whats happening, but I can't make sense of it @SandeshKhutalSaheb

`I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(291)] "Initialized app ", source: https://www.buildai.space/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-e93cf2deab20c74e.js (291)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1251)] "User  null", source: https://www.buildai.space/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-e93cf2deab20c74e.js (1251)`

Comment: I tried opening the url you have mentioned in my Web View. It opens fine for me

Comment: I tried creating a new project, and it works there, so thanks for the observation @oyeraghib! I may have conflicting imports then.. I will investigate further, thanks

Comment: Is the _binding an error or do you have two bindings declared in the fragment?